Invalid certificate on sg-links.stackoverflow.email
Just received the weekly email from WebMasters, and the links are currently routing to an "Invalid Certificate" error:

Your connection isn't private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from sg-links.stackoverflow.email (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
This server couldn't prove that it's sg-links.stackoverflow.email; its security certificate is from *.sendgrid.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

SSL Labs seems to agree that the certificate isn't currently valid for the domain.


I, also, have recently encountered this issue when using a link which I'd received from SE.

@Slate as this bug affects thousands of people every day who can't open links in the emails (well, they can, but most people will close right away a non secure link) any update on this?

I don't understand why this would be sitting in review for any length of time.  Confirming the cert has expired should only take a minute, and fixing it shouldn't take long either.

It did appear to be resolved when a new version of the email was sent out the following day, so likely a transient issue.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight the issue wasn't necessarily that the cert has expired, but that for some reason the SendGrid servers weren't even attempting to send the matching cert.
